# tar command does not work in bash script with variable

Tags: linux, bash, tar

I am trying to find and untar a tgz file, if i do the same things manually it works fine, but in script it does not works

i have tgz file in current directory as: pini-chart-2.0.0-0.0-15.tgz

and running the script:

```
#! /bin/sh.
pini= $(find . -name 'pini-chart-2*' -printf '%f\n')

echo $pini
tar -xvf $pini
```

find command works well but the tar command does not
output:

```
pini-chart-2.0.0-0.0-15.tgz

tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

but i do the same things manually it works please help!

Comment: the newline may be causing trouble for you

Comment: You're not setting the variable correctly.

Comment: `xvzf` to use gzip to decompress it

Comment: i ran:
again with removing the newline and with xvzf but new error came:

pini-chart-2.0.0-0.0-15.tgz
tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: Wrong shebang! Its not bash, and not sh.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot most of the problems here...